# Route serve both param and request body nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

I have question about route to get both request from param and body

My route is to delete user. It looks like this:

```
router.delete("/delete/:id",middleware, async (req, res) => {
   //firstly, I get param:
   var userId = req.params.id || '';

   //if emty, it will get request from body
   if(!userId){
     const listId = req.userIds
   }
});
```

I perform request but it shows error: `Cannot DELETE /api/users/delete`

```
http://localhost:5000/api/users/delete/
```

Can you explain me what wrong with my issue?

Comment: You should pass `id` in the URL

Comment: @Subburaj if I do want id, it will request from body. is possible?

Comment: If you don't pass `id` means the above route is not accessible. It expects `/delete/id` to resolve the route

Comment: As @Subburaj said add id after delete in the route /delete/id

Comment: thank you all, I see. It is just because I want delete multiples users instead of one user. I also do not want to parse it to param with the list of users.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your latest comment you will need a route for collection delete as well as the model route.  Here is some "pseudocode":

```
// model form
router.delete("/delete/:id",middleware, async (req, res) => {
   var userId = req.params.id

   // made up backend service - add error handling, etc
   await dataService.users.delete(userId);
   res.sendStatus(200);  // again with error stuff
});

// collection form
router.delete("/delete",middleware, async (req, res) => {
   var userIds = req.body.userIds; // assumes use of bodyParser
   for (userId in userIds) {
       // made up backend service - add error handling, etc
       await dataService.users.delete(userId);
       res.sendStatus(200);  // again with error stuff
   }     
});
```